# TImerTask on paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, timer, timertask

I have used a TimerTask to add a timer on a loop on one of my classes which is called by the paint component class. Basically there are white circles on the page already painted, there is then a for loop which reads a value from an array and depending on the range of the value the circle will change colour. each circle should represent the next value in the array. but its not working. I am a basic programmer and really don't understand whats going wrong. I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hand. here is my code so far:

```
public DoThePaint() {



    String fileName;
    fileName = "/Users/Desktop/test2.txt";
    read = new Reader(fileName);
    read.displayArrayList();

    panel = new JPanel();
    newImage = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("resource/background2T.png")).getImage();

    circlesT = new ArrayList<Shape>();
    circlesT.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(197.0f, 352.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f));
    circlesT.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(247.0f, 307.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f));
    circlesT.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(152.0f, 303.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f));
    circlesT.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(172.0f, 372.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f));
    circlesT.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(223.0f, 378.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f));
    circlesT.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(273.0f, 285.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f));
    circlesT.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(130.0f, 281.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f));
    circlesT.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(148.0f, 393.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f));
    circlesT.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(246.0f, 403.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f));
    circlesT.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(297.0f, 264.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f));
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    drawShapes(g, circlesT);

}

public void drawShapes(Graphics g, final ArrayList<Shape> circlesT) {
    final Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D) g;
    ga.drawImage(newImage, 0, 0, null);



    for (int i = 0; i < circlesT.size(); i++) {
        ga.draw(circlesT.get(i));
        ga.setPaint(Color.white);
        ga.fill(circlesT.get(i));
    }



    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask t;
    t = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {


                if (read.temp.get(i) < 31 && read.temp.get(i) > 30) {
                    ga.draw(circlesT.get(i));
                    ga.setPaint(Color.green);
                    ga.fill(circlesT.get(i));
                } else if (read.temp.get(i) < 32 && read.temp.get(i) > 31) {
                    ga.draw(circlesT.get(i));
                    ga.setPaint(Color.red);
                    ga.fill(circlesT.get(i));
                } else if (read.temp.get(i) < 33 && read.temp.get(i) > 32) {
                    ga.draw(circlesT.get(i));
                    ga.setPaint(Color.yellow);
                    ga.fill(circlesT.get(i));
                }

            }
        }
    };
    repaint();
    timer.schedule(t, 0, 5000);

}
```

Comment: Sorry dude but no one is going to debug your code for you. Do you know how to debug? I suggest you try it and then post more information if you are still stuck.

Comment: its not that its not working. the painted items seem to flicker then all disappear after a certain amount of time. so nothing will be painted..really confused as to what i am doing wrong

Comment: a)don't put any logic into the paint methods b) never-add call repaint in the paint cycle

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but this is a hall of horrors you made: within `paintComponent()` you are creating a `new Timer`, a `new TimerTask` and eventually calling `repaint()`.

1. `paintComponent()`: all you should do is painting operations (drawing images, filling circles, drawing lines, drawing text, ... on the `Graphics`). That is all you should do.
2. Calling `repaint()` will eventually trigger `paintComponent()` to be invoked again--> recreates the timer, the timer task and recalling repaint()-->paintComponent()->repaint()-->... You get the point, you have just created an infinite loop eating up your resources
3. I have no idea of what your `Reader` class does and what data it holds. I can see two things that I would change: `temp` should be `private` and be accessed properly with a getter or some other access method. Your conditions in your loop are very strict, are you sure all values will match one of the 3 conditions (btw, your condition are all `false` if `read.temp.get(i)` returns an `int` or `Integer`).
4. To fix all these issues, drop the Timer, drop the TimerTask and within your first `for-loop` lookup directly the color of the circles and draw them properly immediately. If at some point, you want to update the display, then you can call `repaint()`
5. Btw, your `TimerTask` is not run on the EDT (Event dispatching thread) but you still access UI-related stuff from within it. That violates the fact that all UI-related tasks should be performed on the EDT (using Swing `Timer` or `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`)
6. In your `TimerTask` you access `Graphics2D ga` which is the same as the `Graphics g` provided by `paintComponent()`: you cannot access that `Graphics` object outside the scope of the `paintComponent` method. `Graphics` are created and disposed and should therefore not be used outside their scope. In general, you should never keep a reference to a `Graphics` object (nor use the method `getGraphics()` which may be tempting but source of all kind of bad headaches).

Answer (score 1):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how painting works in Swing. No big deal though, everyone has to start somewhere.

It looks like you are wanting to do animation. In that cause your paintComponent method should draw the state of your object at a particular point in time. Any timer that is controlling the timing of the paint should be in another class.

For simple animation a TimerTask is just fine. If you are wanting to animate a game or something needed good performance I recommend the animation class in Chapter 2 of the book Killer Game Programming in Java by Andrew Davison. You can actually read Chapter 2 at Amazon in their Look Inside feature.

Comment: thank you for your response. my painted object is already drawn in a certain location. if i dont have a timer all the circles change colour at the same time according to the value coming in. all i want to do is change the colour of the cirlces one by one. so the user can visualy see the change taking place.

Comment: do you mind if you show me code wise where to put the timer task.for example show me how it should look compared to my code ive given above.im really confused by some of the feed back although i do appreciate it..this is due on friday and im really stuck.